# Ubuntu Intermittently Freezes on Load

Tags: 18.04, freeze, msi

I installed Ubuntu on my MSI GF63 Laptop. My Specs are as follows:
Intel Core i5 9300H (Quad Core)
8 GB RAM
nVidia GTX 1050
Intel 660p 512GB SSD( 140GB + 15GB Swap for Linux)

My system freezes intermittently on load. If I play music, run a nodeJS and Java Server, Open Firefox and VS Code. The System freezes intermittently. I tried keeping htop running to see if I was facing any bottlenecks, but I found neither the CPUs nor the Memory to be running out of capacity during these occurances. Usually Audio does not lag, music and calls stay on mostly even though sometimes it slightly stutters, but the mouse won't move and Alt + Tab won't work

I tried installing DRM KMS as suggested in [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/528727/how-do-i-solve-periodic-mouse-lag-on-linux-mint-mate) but with no avail
I tried switching to my nVidia GPU use X-Server, but that didn't fix it either. I'm kind of running out of options since I'm not able to diagnose any bottlenecks.

```
➜  ~ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        6.5G        125M        573M        988M        270M
Swap:           15G        1.0G         14G
➜  ~ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
➜  ~ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=a0c6ff2a-8e8c-428a-8ab6-37ca22bdb822 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Gnome Extension Commands return the following:

```
➜ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions         
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb  3 23:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb  3 23:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 23:54 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 23:54 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
➜ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions     
ls: cannot access '/home/maverick/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

[top output on fresh reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMDVL.png)

[image: top output when lag was observed without excessive load]

`free -h` output when lag was observed without excessive load

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        2.5G        2.6G        394M        2.5G        4.5G
Swap:           15G        199M         15G
```

Output for `lshw -C memory`

```
sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for maverick: 
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 1
       version: E16R3IMS.309
       date: 03/26/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3b
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M471A1K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 32E64524
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 45
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 46
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 47
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a441a000-a441bfff memory:a4422000-a4422fff
```

Comment: Your link has nothing to do with DKMS. If you switch to the internal Intel video, does the problem still occur? What version Nvidia driver?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Sorry for my ignorance, I'm not quite familiar with the terms, it was the DRM KMS Module

Comment: You didn't answer my questions.

Comment: Really Sorry,  Yes it occurs for both GPUs, I had switched to nVidia to know if it was an Intel GPU issue

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `top`.

Comment: I had done some updates using the GUI Software Updater and disabled secure-boot yesterday which fixed it for the day(Tried Running VS Code, 2xNode Servers, Tomcat Server, MySQL, Postgres, DBeaver, Postman, Slack, Spotify without any lags ), but now it's back again (with just VS Code, Firefox, Spotify, 1 node server)

Comment: There are lots of suspect things with your `top` command output. Your swap is excessive @ 16G, and we'll deal with that later, but more importantly, something is swapping like crazy, and that's why the freezes/lags. You have two gnome-shell processes, and three apps... slack, firefox, and code consuming a lot of memory... and spotify and slack each have two processes running. I don't know what slack is. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and ... next comment...

Comment: Reboot the system, then show me a fresh copy of the `top` command. How many tabs do you have open in Firefox? Why is pulseaudio running at such a strange priority?

Comment: I've added the details you've mentioned. Hope it brings better clarity

Comment: Thanks for the new info! I need one more thing before I write an answer for you. `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help. I'm sorry for my stubbornness but I find it a bit hard to believe my RAM can't handle it, because sometimes it's lag-free with a large number of processes, and sometimes laggy with just Firefox VSCode and 1 Node Server. I have ordered another 8Gig RAM as you've suggested. I'm also setting up my desktop which also has an i5 and 8GB RAM I'm trying to set that up and test my same setup there and see if it lags.

Comment: As you initially said, I feel like maybe it's one of my applications swapping like crazy as you rightly mentioned that's causing the problem. I'm trying to find out what that application is

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the answer and added the top and free-h outputs when lag was observed without excessive load. Can you tell me if even this maybe because of lack of RAM. because I honestly believe it's not

Comment: The only thing I notice is two gnome-shell processes, and a lot of swap activity. Reboot, and do `ps auxc | grep gnome-shell`, look for two processes, and as you start applications/etc, see if there's something that's starting the second gnome-shell. Maximize your terminal window, and show me a full screen `top` and maybe I'll see more. Use copy/paste instead of screenshot, if you can.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I moved to Ubuntu 20.04 and things seem to be working well here. I'm accepting the answer because my RAM is still a bit of the bottle neck even though it wasn't what caused the unbearable stuttering. I think it was probably a driver issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your freezes and lags is because you're running out of memory, and the system is swapping. You're running a lot of processes, and quitting those processes, before the reboot, cleared up a lot of problems. Memory and swap were reclaimed, and the system was then freeze/lag free.

**DRM KMS**

Undo your DRM KMS modifications, as they didn't resolve the problem.

**RAM**

You need to increase your RAM from 8G to 16G. You always want to configure memory in equal size, matched pairs, of RAM SODIMMs so that the system can take speed advantage of memory interleaving. To configure your memory, add another 8G RAM SODIMM with these specifications...

```
 description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
  product: M471A1K43CB1-CTD
  vendor: Samsung
  serial: 32E64524
  size: 8GiB
  width: 64 bits
```

**Swap**

We'll make swap changes last, after increasing the RAM.

You need to decrease your swap partition from 16G, and we'll switch you over to a /swapfile of 4G. Once completed, you can allocate the 16G swap partition to your / or /home partition.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Comment out this line in /etc/fstab...

```
UUID=a0c6ff2a-8e8c-428a-8ab6-37ca22bdb822 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Add this line to /etc/fstab...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Reboot. Verify proper /swapfile operation using `free -h`.